# initializing final Boolean in if-Statement

Tags: java

So I am trying to set leapyear to true in the if statement, but when I do so it tells me thatleapYear in the second if-Statement is not Initilized.
Thanks for your help!

```
public class LeapYear {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int year = 1600 + (int)(Math.random() * 500);
        final boolean leapYear;
        
        if(year%4==0){
           leapYear = true;
        }

        if (leapYear){
            System.out.println(year + " leap");
        } else {
            System.out.println(year + " notleap");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If we initialize a `final` variable in an `if`-branch, we have to also initialize it in the corresponding `else`-branch. If no `else`-branch exists, we must create one.

Comment: What happens to `leapYear`, if `year%4` is **not** `0`?

Comment: That's not the actual definition of a leap year. Divisible by 4 or (divisible by 100 and divisible by 400). 1900 was not a leap year!

Comment: 4 answers and nobody is cluing in to the fact that you're making your boolean work needlessly complicated. All you need is `final boolean leapYear = year % 4 == 0`. Note that this is a lie - leapYear math is much more complicated than that. If it's divisible by 400, it's a leap year. otherwise, if it's divisible by 100, it's not. Otherwise if its divisible by 4, it is. Otherwise it is not.

Comment: @rzwitserloot that is - of course - possible (and more efficient), but not the core of the question. The core of the question is initialization of a `final` variable in a branching statement.

Answer (score 3):

If we declare a `final` variable outside an `if`-`else`-statement and initialize it in the `if`-branch, we have to initialize it in the corresponding `else`-branch as well. If no `else`-branch exists, we must create one, otherwise the variable is uninitialized [iff.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) the `if`-branch is not entered.

```
class Ideone {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int year = 1600 + (int)(Math.random() * 500);
    final boolean leapYear;

    if(year%4==0){
      leapYear = true;
    } else {
      leapYear = false;
    }

    if (leapYear){
      System.out.println(year + " leap");
    } else {
      System.out.println(year + " notleap");
    }
  }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/RhZInG)

Answer (score 2):

leap Year variable may not always be initialized

```
    public class LeapYear {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int year = 1600 + (int)(Math.random() * 500);
            boolean leapYear = false;
            
            if(year%4==0){
               leapYear = true;
            }
   
            if (leapYear){
                System.out.println(year + " leap");
            } else {
                System.out.println(year + " notleap");
            }
         }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class LeapYear {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int year = 1600 + (int)(Math.random() * 500);
        boolean leapYear = year % 4 == 0;
        
        if (leapYear){
            System.out.println(year + " leap");
        } else {
            System.out.println(year + " notleap");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove **final** before the name of the variable and initialize the variable to false

for Example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int year = 1600 + (int)(Math.random() * 500);
    boolean leapYear = false;
    
        if(year%4==0){
           leapYear = true;
       
         }

    if (leapYear){
        System.out.println(year + " leap");
    } else {
        System.out.println(year + " notleap");
    }

}
```

Comment: "*You have to remove **final** before the name of the variable*" - [Nope](https://ideone.com/RhZInG).

Comment: what nope? can't understand

Comment: The statement is false. We do not have to remove the `final` modifier.

Comment: but if we mark final, the first if-bloc generate an error...so decide what do you want

Comment: Look at the link behind the "Nope". It shows a working example, with the variable still being `final`. Alternatively, look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69874160/4216641).

Comment: yes but it's sounds very bad..because, if we remove "final" and execute the code like the mine, I think that it is more clear and efficient..but If you must have the variable marked as final, I can't say nothing and you right..

Comment: I would strongly advice to always use `final` if `final` semantics are wanted. It prevents us from accidentally changing a value that was not intended to be changed (at least, as long as it is a primitive, for objects, we have to rely on immutability). Furhtermore, `final` can improve performance in certain cases.

Comment: Sure but if you have to change the value of the variable, after one if-statement, it doesn't have sense to mark it as **final** ...BTW, you're right man